# Battery issue ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, power-management, laptop, hp, battery

The battery doesnt seem to charge. It is stack to 18%. It shows charging but does not:
[image]

Using

```
upower -e
```

I get the following output:

```
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ADP1
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

Using

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

I get the following:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               HP
  model:                Primary
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Πεμ 28 Ιουλ 2022 08:50:20 πμ EEST (105 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              7,8848 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         42,8736 Wh
    energy-full-design:  42,8736 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             15,415 V
    percentage:          18%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-low-charging-symbolic'
```

**energy-full** and **energy-full-design** have the same output which might mean that its in good health. However, the battery does not charge.

Any idea why it is not charging?

**Edit**

Model:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information"
```

```
System Information
    Manufacturer: HP
    Product Name: OMEN by HP Laptop 15-dc1xxx
    Version:  
    Serial Number: ****
    UUID: *****
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: ****
    Family: *****
```

Comment: What is the make and model? Battery charging is often at least somewhat controlled by the BIOS.

Comment: @mchid edited my answer. its an HP Omen 15.